# Oracle manually update statistics on all tables

Tags: oracle, statistics

Is there a way to update all statistics for all tables regardless of the owner?

I found this sniplet, but I'm not sure if this will grab all tables....

```
BEGIN
   FOR A IN ( SELECT owner FROM SYS.all_tables ) LOOP
      execute immediate
        EXEC dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats( 'A.owner', cascade='TRUE');
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM SYS.all_tables

Answer (score 24):

Use [DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_stats.htm#i1036194):

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_database_stats;
end;
/
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @SysDragon My answer was both a function and a link.  I added an `exec` and `;` to make it more clear.

Comment: And as predicted, the link is broken.

Comment: @PecosBill Thanks for fixing the link!  Seems like Oracle breaks the links to their documentation every few years, I'll need to check a lot of my other answers.

Answer (score 11):

No the [`DBMS_STATS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i1036456) package can do at most one schema at a time.

You can use the script below to gather stats for all objects types in all schemas. The one you listed has a couple of issues (needless execute immediate, `A.owner' is a string but it should be an object, etc).

You can add additional schemas to skip in the `IN` list as you probably don't want to do this for the built in schemas (they're mostly static anyway so it'd be waste). Also, you'll need to have the appropriate privileges for each schema you are gathering stats on (or be logged in as a DBA).

Gather stats on all objects (probably what you really want):

```
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT * 
                FROM all_users
                WHERE username NOT IN ('SYS','SYSDBA'))
    LOOP
        dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(rec.username);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Gather stats on just tables:

```
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT * 
                FROM all_tables
                WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS','SYSDBA'))
    LOOP
        dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(rec.owner, rec.table_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a modification to @sehrope procedure to skip locked stats and IOT tables as they will through exceptions.

```
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT a.owner, a.table_name 
                FROM all_tables a, dba_tab_statistics  s
                WHERE a.owner NOT IN ('SYS','SYSDBA')
                AND 
                (a.iot_type IS NULL
                OR
                a.iot_type != 'IOT_OVERFLOW')
                and a.owner = s.owner and a.table_name = s.table_name and s.STATTYPE_LOCKED is null)
    LOOP
        dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(rec.owner, rec.table_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
```